# JSONObject why does getString not getting any value here?

Tags: java, android, json, getstring

I am having problems parsing a JSONObject send betweend my Server and the Android Device.

It looks like this:

> {
>   "items":[{"value":"100","longitude":"11.584565599030755","latitude":"48.25420604757366","type":"timer"},{"value":"50","longitude":"11.695457342867675","latitude":"48.34626913462275","type":"rare"},{"value":"1","longitude":"11.6782003186674","latitude":"48.33575480986649","type":"normal"},{"value":"1","longitude":"11.707280558203376","latitude":"48.19109880886268","type":"normal"}],
>   "locations":[{"username":"babine","gender":"female","longitude":"11.670796394348145","latitude":"48.26356506347656"}]
>   }

This is what my device is actually recieving from the server.
Now split this up like this:

```
JSONArray locations= json.getJSONArray("locations");
List<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for (int i= 0; i < locations.length(); i++) {
     list.add(locations.getJSONObject(i));
}
LocationEvent.players = list;

JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("items");
list.clear();
for (int i= 0; i < items.length(); i++){
    list.add(items.getJSONObject(i));
}
Item.items = list;
```

Where Item.items and LocationEvent.players are from type:

> List<\JSONObject>

Later i am creating Overlays for each of those List items like this:

```
players.clear();
for(JSONObject player: LocationEvent.getAllPlayers()){    
    UserOverlay user = new UserOverlay(game, player.getString("username"), player.getString("gender"), Double.valueOf(player.getString("latitude")), Double.valueOf(player.getString("longitude")));
     players.add(user);
}

items.clear();
for(JSONObject item : Item.getAllItems()){
    ItemOverlay itemOv = new ItemOverlay(game, type, Double.valueOf(item.getString("longitude")), Double.valueOf(item.getString("latitude")));
    items.add(itemOv);
}
```

And here is where the JSONException occurs:

> org.json.JSONException: No value for username

I am not quite sure what i am doing wrong here...maybe you guys can help me out. If you need more information just let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're reusing the same list to store the items:

```
List<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for (int i= 0; i < locations.length(); i++) {
     list.add(locations.getJSONObject(i));
}
LocationEvent.players = list;
```

Here, `Location.players` contains the locations

```
JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("items");
list.clear();
```

But now it doesn't contain anything anymore: you've just cleared it.

```
for (int i= 0; i < items.length(); i++){
    list.add(items.getJSONObject(i));
}
Item.items = list;
```

And now `Location.players` contains the items, just as `Item.items`, since both variables reference the same list.

Comment: oh..i did not realize that this does not copy the whole list. But it makes total sense now. Thanks a lot. Will mark you answer as correct as soon as i can.